# git add not adding files in specific subdirectory

Tags: git

I have searched on this site and found similar issues, although none of the solutions are working. I will list all that i have tried here so as to save time after giving more detail on the issue.

My repository has a folder inside it, containing the english version of the html files from a website i am developing. But when i try to add the changes i made to said files, it does not add on the working directory for it to be commited.

Names of the folders goes:

site <- Main directory where repository was initiaded ( git init was done here) 
en <- Where the files that i can't put in the commit are located.

Total path: site/en/filename.html

I have tried:

```
git add .
git add *
git add en/.
git add en/ .
git add en/*
git add en/ *
git add --all
```

I am trying to avoid using the -force command for good practice. The result of those commands are the same with the exception of git add en/*, which i will also list. The `git status`command returns:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   en (modified content)
```

while `git add en/*` returns when the command is entered:

```
fatal: Pathspec 'en/about.html' is in submodule 'en'
```

Something is wrong and i can't figure it out what. A file on the css folder is added correctly to the working directory and is commited as intended. Same goes for all other folders inside the repository, the changes are added correctly. The issue seems to be only with the /en folder. Any ideas?

PS: If relevant: Using Ubuntu 15.10 and the remote repository is located on BitBucket.

Comment: The answer is pretty clear from `fatal: Pathspec 'en/about.html' is in submodule 'en'`: there's a submodule named `en` in the way.  You are getting every `en/*` file from the submodule, not from the tree you're in now.  You will need to put those files into the submodule (which is a separate Git repository, using Git's submodules, also known as "sob-modules" since they make their users cry with frustration :-) ).

Comment: I do my best to avoid submodules myself, so I'm not sure of the "best" way to deal with this, but yes, you must commit them to the submodule. The problem is that this is only the *beginning* of what you must do: you must then instruct the superproject to use the *newer version* of the subproject / submodule. Depending on your setup, this can take many more steps.

Comment: I see!

I moved to the sub-directory en, commited the files there, moved up and added once more. The sub-directory en was then added to the working directory correctly.

But why did git created a submodule on en/ and not on other folders, such as images/ or css/? They both have other directories inside them also. Just trying to get a better understanding of git ins and outs. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Git only creates submodules when directly instructed to do so, by having the submodule listed in the superproject. This is what submodules are about: they say "when using this repo, retrieve another repo." The problem with this is the "other repo" is *frozen at one particular commit*, whose ID is specified in the superproject. To change any subproject to some other commit requires an annoying update sequence. I can do it manually but, because I avoid submodules, I don't know what the "right way" is for others to automate this.

Comment: Ah, i see. I must have done something by accident. I will try looking up to see if i can remove this sub-module from my current repository.

Thank you all very much.