# How do I specify that a project subfolder is there for organizational purposes and should contain data, and isn't a submodule or anything else?

Tags: git

I have a project structure, which is:

```
.
├── data
│   ├── some_data.csv
│   └── sub_data_folder
│       *there is nothing in here, which is wrong because locally this is here for 
|        organizational purposes and should contain data.  Git may think this is a 
|        submodule or another repository, but it should be neither.*
└── notebooks
    ├── some_notebook.ipynb
    ├── sub_notebook_folder
    |   * the contents of this folder are incorrect for the same reasons as above *
```

When I pushed this project to the remote repository on Github, I noticed that the folder that should have contained files did not and there was a white arrow on the folders.  See the StackExchange question I linked below called "Github folders have white arrow on them".

**What did I try to do?**

Google "What is a submodule in git", which gave me: "Git submodules allow you to keep a git repository as a subdirectory of another git repository." That is not what I need.

Google "What is a repository in git", which gave me: "A Git repository is a central storage location for managing and tracking changes in files and directories."  I already have this as "." in my diagram, I don't need "sub_data_folder" and "sub_notebook_folder" to be duplicates of this function.

Google "How do I tell git that a folder in my project is meant for organizational purposes and should contain data." Irrelevant results, so maybe it was a bad query.

Run `git rm --cached sub_data_folder`

Run `git add sub_data_folder` which gave me:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: data/sub_data_folder
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> data/sub_data_folder
```

So now git is telling me that I should either be adding this folder as a repository (which I mentioned above is not what I need) or as a submodule (which again is not what I need).

Now I google "How can a folder exist in git if it is not a submodule or a repository?", which gives me: "A folder can exist in Git if it is not a submodule or a repository if it is a working tree.". So maybe I must specify that it is a working tree?

Run `git worktree add sub_data_folder` which gives me:
`fatal: 'sub_data_folder/' is not a valid branch name.`

At this point I give up in frustration and take a break.

**Did you try to search for similar StackOverflow issues, and why didn't those work?**

[git add not adding files in specific subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837333/git-add-not-adding-files-in-specific-subdirectory)

In the above stack overflow, there is no answer, and the comments did not seem relevant to my issue.  I could not gather useful information from the comments.

[GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)

Ah yes! This seems to be the exact issue I was experiencing! However, one of the answers in this question is:
Run `git clone --recurse-submodules`
So I did this and the terminal gave me:
`fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.`
I looked at the user's answer again and he/she said...
"...and the content of the folder would remain empty)".
Well, I don't want it to be empty, it should contain data, so maybe that command isn't applicable.

**EDIT 1 for clarity:**

sub_data_folder as it exists locally on my machine is a folder which contains .csv files.  The function of this folder should be preserved as I push it to Github.  At one point, it appeared that Git wanted this folder to be empty and not contain .csv files.

Comment: what about `.gitignore` file

Comment: `and should contain data` what else but files with data can there be in a folder

Comment: It's not clear to me why you think you have to do _anything_, you don't mention the problem that started this whole process. If you have a directory containing files in your repo, git has absolutely no problem with that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added more explanation below the tree diagram, hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: @rioV8 wouldn't a .gitignore tell Git to ignore the folder completely, and thus the folder would not appear in it's correct form (as a folder containing data) in Github?

Comment: Added Edit 1 for clarity

Comment: Apparently `sub_data_folder` is a Git repository (because it contains another `.git` directory), is that intentional?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No it wasn't intentional.  They were created as I was running other commands and I don't remember what that command was.  But thank you anyway, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved because the structure as it appears on GitHub mirrors what I have locally, thus it is correct.

mkrieger1's comment helped push me in the right direction.  At some point, `.git` files were created in the subfolders.  I don't know why.  I didn't catch them initially because I had only done an `ls -a` in the root folder and saw the `.git` folder there, which is the correct `.git` folder. If I had ran `find . --name .git` instead, I would have found the other `.git` folders hiding in the subfolders as well.

Once those were deleted, I needed to delete the subfolders from the git cache again by running `git rm --cached sub_data_folder/`.

VSCode then recognized that this was a subfolder that contained data (.csv) files.  The .csv files showed up and were ready to be pushed.  At this point, I entered a commit message and synced changes.

Comment: how did these `.git` folders get created

Comment: @rioV8 I don't know but I assume they were created as I was running other commands in an attempt to resolve the issue.

Comment: the issue was that you had these `.git` folders, so any command to resolve the issue would not create them, only `git init` and `git clone` does